# Why does MatIterator_ have an underscore in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv

Why does [MatIterator_](http://physics.nyu.edu/grierlab/manuals/opencv/classcv_1_1MatIterator__.html) have an underscore in its name, instead of being named just `MatIterator`? It's such an odd choice for a class name I assume it has some significance. Is it a naming convention in OpenCV, or is it arbitrary?

Comment: Looking at http://physics.nyu.edu/grierlab/manuals/opencv/annotated.html it looks like it is used as a convention to distinguish between a templated and non templated version, i.e. cv::MatConstIterator vs cv::MatConstIterator_< _Tp >, probably things like cv::Point_< _Tp > had a non templated version as well?

Comment: They don't explicitly say that, but looking at the classes, indeed all those who end in underscore have templates. But there is no MatIterator without an underscore here. Or maybe there used to be?